How to make an Angular component more generic to accept multiple data types as @Input?
I have a component that fetch data from backend, display it in table and allows user to make a selection.
The whole component is based on the type of the fetched data, so it is strongly restraints to this type (Item).
Now I need the component to work with slighty different type of data based on an @Input.
I don't know how to make it work with Typescript.
Simplified component looks like this :
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() public selectedItems: Item[] = [];
@Output() public validateButtonEmitter = new EventEmitter<Item[]>();
@Output() public cancelButtonEmitter = new EventEmitter<Item[]>();

constructor(private readonly facade: Facade) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.facade.setInitialSelectedItems(this.selectedItems);
    this.facade.getDataFromBackend();
}

public validateButtonHandler(selectedItems: Item[]): void {
    this.validateButtonEmitter.emit(selectedItems);
}

public cancelButtonHandler(selectedItems: Item[]): void {
    this.cancelButtonEmitter.emit(selectedItems);
}

}
My plan is to add an @Input parameter to pass the desired data to be fetched. then I will modify the getDataFromBackend() method to accept an argument, allowing dynamic route selection based on the input data. However, I'm uncertain about how to refactor all the methods within the component to be more generic regarding data types.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

this is all Item, but you can read into TypeGuards and narrowing

@user3791775 Thanks for the hint. However, am I correct in understanding that Type guards require me to specify every possible type in every method?

components can Be generic. as example the code in the question would look like this
// generic could be restrictive. for example TItem extends {selected: boolean}
// will make sure that items passed have a selected field
export class MyComponent<TItem> implements OnInit { 
@Input() public selectedItems: TItem[] = [];
@Output() public validateButtonEmitter = new EventEmitter<TItem[]>();
@Output() public cancelButtonEmitter = new EventEmitter<TItem[]>();

constructor(private readonly facade: Facade<TItem>) {} // most probably you want your facade to be generic as well

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.facade.setInitialSelectedItems(this.selectedItems);
    this.facade.getDataFromBackend();
}

public validateButtonHandler(selectedItems: TItem[]): void {
    this.validateButtonEmitter.emit(selectedItems);
}

public cancelButtonHandler(selectedItems: TItem[]): void {
    this.cancelButtonEmitter.emit(selectedItems);
}


Thanks for your answer. How does this  is supposed to work exactly ? I am not familiar with this

if you bind to the component's numbers array [seleccted]="nums", then everything else generic (in this case 2 outputs) will have the same TItem type - they will emit numbers. it is like typescript function with generic arguments and return type

It means I should make the wall library generic, including the store?
This component is a small part of lib.

depends on how the library api is designed. if you are making http queries inside of the library - then yes

You can use the concept of base component and the extend it with whatever input type you pass to T.
export abstract class MyComponentBase<T> implements OnInit {
@Input() public selectedItems: T[] = [];
@Output() public validateButtonEmitter = new EventEmitter<T[]>();
@Output() public cancelButtonEmitter = new EventEmitter<T[]>();

constructor(private readonly facade: Facade) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.facade.setInitialSelectedItems(this.selectedItems);
    this.facade.getDataFromBackend();
}

public validateButtonHandler(selectedItems: T[]): void {
    this.validateButtonEmitter.emit(selectedItems);
}

public cancelButtonHandler(selectedItems: T[]): void {
    this.cancelButtonEmitter.emit(selectedItems);
}

// Extent the components with different type like
export class MyComponentChild1 extends MyComponentBase<string>{}

export class MyComponentChild2 extends MyComponentBase<Item>{}

export class MyComponentChild3 extends MyComponentBase<'any-custom-type'>{}

For this you might need to modify the facade class to generic or make the setInitialSelectedItems method accept the pre defined types you might need.
public setInitialSelectedItems(data: string | Item | 'any-custom-type') { }
